# Module google_auth_httplib2 not found after pip installing google-cloud How can I fix it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I used pip to install [cloud-storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python), like this:

```
$ pip install --upgrade google-cloud
```

When I started my application, I got an error that said no module named google_auth_httplib2 was found. I used pip list and verified that the package was installed, yet the import kept failing. Should I install it in my project's folder, like this?

```
$ pip install google-cloud -t [my_path]
```

UPDATE:

Just for clarity, the error arises in the google-auth-httplib2 module, not the httplib2 module. I recently installed it in the lib folder of my project: my_project/lib/google_cloud_storage. If I try importing google.cloud.storage from lib.google_cloud_storage, it will work it's way until it gets to google_auth_httplib2 module, where it throws a not found error. I've tried placing that module in the same folder as the one calling it, and not even then will it work.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in the project.

Comment: Already tried that, and I get the same problem :(

Comment: Can you update the OP to show your project directory tree?  You don't need `google-cloud` in the project.  You need the httplib2 module

Comment: I can even call "from google.cloud import storage" in the IDLE shell and it works. But when I use that same line in my project, it gives me that error. I have no idea what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem, I'll leave the answer just in case anyone else runs into it. I created a folder named google-cloud in lib and used pip:

```
pip install google-cloud -t [my_project]/lib/google-cloud
```

And then in appengine_config.py I added:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib/google-cloud')
```