# No module named google_auth_httplib2

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, httplib2, six

**Goal:** Use GAE with Python and Google Cloud Storage to store and serve an image more efficiently to ultimately use the image API.

**Problem:** Cannot find correct modules (httplib2 and six) despite successful install.

---

**Run time example**

**Python Code Sample A:**

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
import webapp2
```

**Returns Sample A:**

> ImportError: No module named google_auth_httplib2

Note: Also had a similar error for six. "no module named six"

---

**Installed Details**

**python installed at:**

```
C:\Python27
```

**six installed at:**

```
C:\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
```

**httplib2 installed at:**

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg-info
```

**Running “C:>pip install httplib2” in the command line returns:**

```
“Requirement already satisfied: httplib2 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages”
```

**Running “C:>pip install six” in the command line returns:**

```
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
```

**GAE Cloud Storage Client installed at:**

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient-1.9.22.1-py2.7.egg-info
```

**GAE SDK Server Hosting using "dev_appserver.py ." at:**

```
C:\Users\sebastian\Documents\Web Projects\Cookbook
```

This location also contains the app.yaml file.

**Copied modules to app.yaml location**

Copied the `httplib2` and `six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg` folders to my `app.yaml` directory.

---

Appendix 1:

**App.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

    - url: /
      script: homegcs.app

    - url: /static
      static_dir: static

    - url: /.*
      script: home.app

    - url: /index\.html
      script: home.app

    - url: /stylesheets
      static_dir: stylesheets

    - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
      static_files: static/\1
      upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$

    - url: /admin/.*
      script: admin.app
      login: admin

    - url: /.*
      script: not_found.app
```

[Folder structure containing App.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmRju.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your packages either need to be uploaded with the project, or added in app.yaml, if they are available in App Engine.  `six` is an available library, so, in `app.yaml`, add:

```
libraries:
- name: six
  version: "1.9.0"
```

If you put the `httplib2` package at the same level as `app.yaml`, it should upload with the project, and be available in production.

Another user added `google_auth_httplib2` as a package as well, and uploaded it with the project.  Though I think that should be available directly:

[Module google_auth_httplib2 not found after pip installing google-cloud How can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905503/module-google-auth-httplib2-not-found-after-pip-installing-google-cloud-how-can)

** You also have an issue in your url handlers in `app.yaml`.  This is a wildcard for all urls:

```
- url: /.*
    script: home.app
```

So, every handler below that will not ever be hit.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly solves 2 of 4 of the apparent issues. (six and yaml handlers). I've added a picture of the folder structure, as I already have both httplib2 and google_auth_httplib2 in my app.yaml directory but it still throws the same error with regards google_auth_httplib2 not found.

Comment: `httplib2` and `google_auth_httplib2` are 2 different packages.  Your error is that your code is looking for `google_auth_httplib2`, while you have `httplib2`.  Switch your code, or use the correct package (see the link in my answer as to how another user did that)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install google-cloud in your project, like this:

```
pip install google-cloud -t [my_project]/lib/google-cloud
```

Make sure you create that google-cloud folder first, inside your lib folder. Once you do that, change or create appengine_config.py (in /my_project) and include this:

```py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib/google-cloud')
```

Everything shoul work now.

Comment: thanks, tht certainly seems to have fixed some of it.

the error now reads

"from google.cloud import storage
Import Error: No module named cloud"

@yamilabugattas

Comment: Are you sure the folder is in the directory specified in appengine_config.py? Make sure you pip install in that folder. Also try adding from __future__ import absolute_import at the beginning of the file.